# Using a custom XYZ tile server in Manifold

Tags: qgis, tiles, tile-server, manifold

I've a custom tile server that returns a tile based on the X/Y/Z values provided in the URL. The thing is just brilliant when used as a gMaps layer.

I can simply add a new Tile Server to QGIS and call it a day, but now a client of ours would like to import the layer to Manifold which doesn't have support for that (I think?).

I've tried exporting the tiles from QGIS using GeoTIFF but the process is way too slow and I failed to find a way of importing the resulting vrt file to Manifold, plus the resulting images had a ton of weird artifacts.

Ideally I'd share the original data with them, but that is not an option.

Should I use a different format when exporting?

Stitch the ~2m tiles and just have a single image spanning the entire US?

Would Radian be of any help there?

Comment: I've never used Manifold, nor do I know the first thing about it, but it says here that it can support TMS, WMTS etc.: http://www.manifold.net/info/radian_sources.shtml There is a subtle difference between TMS and XYZ as far as the y-tile-coordinate goes (https://gist.github.com/tmcw/4954720), but most client applications have an option for that.

Comment: the tile server is custom made so adding support for basically a different type of query is not a problem, I just couldn't find a way to add the source. I'll have another look, but I'm surprised this is such an issue ...

also, who gives their product such a generic name, googling "manifold TMS" mostly returns a list of tractor parts suppliers :)